# Zeroes of a quadratic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, roots, quadratics

Let $m \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \space\space |\space \space f(x) = x^2+(m+1)x-((3/4)m+5/4)\space\space \forall \space\space x \space \in \space \mathbb{R}$

Let $\mathbb{A} = \{x\space|\space f(x)=0\}$

We are to find the range of values of $m$ such that

1. $||\mathbb{A}||=2$
2. $r>3 \space \forall\space r \in \mathbb{A}$

The first condition is basically that the given quadratic polynomial should have two distinct real roots, for which it's necessary and sufficient that the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial is strictly greater than zero, that is

$$(m+1)^2 - 4((3/4)m+5/4) > 0 $$
$$\iff m^2+5m+6 >0$$
$$\iff (m+2)(m+3)>0$$
$$\iff m \in (-\infty, -3)\cup(-2,\infty)$$

The second condition however is related to restricting both the zeroes of the quadratic polynomial in a certain bound(that is, both the zeroes of the quadratic polynomial should be strictly greater than 3). I am unable to think of a condition on $m$ to achieve this restriction.

Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: In your calculation for the first condition, you should have $(m + 1)^2 + 4[(3/4)m + 5/4]$ since the term $(3/4)m + 5/4$ is being subtracted.  Based on your subsequent calculations, it looks like you realized this.

Answer (score 1):

You can write formula for roots as a function of $m$.
$$
x_1 = \frac { -(m + 1) - \sqrt{ (m+2)(m+3) } } {2},\qquad
x_2 = \frac { -(m + 1) + \sqrt{ (m+2)(m+3) } } {2}.
$$
If you want both of them to be greater than 3, it is necessary and sufficient to have minimum greater than 3, that is $x_1 > 3$. This condition gives us inequality with square root
$$
-(m + 1)- \sqrt{ m^2 + 5m + 6 } > 6 \quad \iff \quad
\sqrt{ m^2 + 5m + 6 } < -(m +7).
$$
Since RHS needs to be positive, we assume $m < -7$ and then square inequality to obtain
$$
m^2 + 5m + 6 < m^2 + 14 m + 49 \quad \iff \quad  -43 < 9m.
$$
But $m > -\frac {43} 9$ and $m < -7$ contradict with each other, so there are no parameters $m\in \mathbb R$ such that both conditions 1 & 2 hold.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be informative to look at where the vertex and $ \ x-$intercepts of the function curve are located as a function of $ \ m \ \ . \ $  The vertex form of the quadratic polynomial is

$$ x^2 \ + \ (m + 1)·x \ - \ \frac{3m \ +  \ 5}{4} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \left(x  \ + \  \frac{m + 1}{2} \right)^2 \ - \ \frac{3m \ +  \ 5}{4} \ - \ \frac{ m^2 \ + \ 2m \ +  \ 1}{4}  $$
$$ = \ \ \left(x  \ + \  \frac{m + 1}{2} \right)^2 \ - \ \left( \frac{ m^2 \ + \ 5m \ +  \ 6}{4} \right) \ \ = \ \ \left(x  \ + \  \frac{m + 1}{2} \right)^2 \ - \ \left[ \frac{ (m + 3)·(m + 2)}{4} \right] \ \ .   $$

For $ \ m \ \ge \ -7 \ \ , \ $ the vertex is at or "to the left" of $ \ x \ = \ +3 \ \ \ , \ $ so the smaller of the two zeroes of the polynomial is necessarily less than $ \ 3 \ \ . \ $  (The vertex is   "above" the $ \ x-$axis for $ \ -3 \ \le \ m \ \le \ -2 \ \ , \ $ so there are no zeroes for this interval, and there is a "double zero" at $ \ x \ = \ \frac12 \ $ or $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ $ at the endpoints of this interval for $ \ m \ \ . \ ) $

What happens for $ \ m \ < \ -7 \ \ ? \ $  While the vertex continues to move "downward and to the right" as $ \ m \ $ decreases, we see that the smaller of the two zeroes *remains* less than $ \ 3 \ \ ; \ $ in fact,
$$ \lim_{m \ \rightarrow \ -\infty} \ \frac { -(m + 1) - \sqrt{ \ (m+2)·(m+3)}}{2} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \lim_{m \ \rightarrow \ -\infty} \ \frac { |m| \ - \ 1 \ - \ ( \  |m| \ - \ 5/2 \  )}{2} \ \ = \ \ \frac34 \ \ . $$

Hence, there is **no** value of $ \ m  \ $ for which both zeroes of the given polynomial is greater than $ \ 3 \ \ . $